# Pseudo localization in Android Emulator not available

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, android-emulator

I would like to enable "English (XA)" and "عربى" (XB) locales en-XA and ar-XB
to make sure my app layouts are ready for translation, similar to what the article describes [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/pseudo-localization-testing-in-android/).  However, it is not available in the official Android emulator settings.  I have tried several images and cannot find these pseudo-localization languages.  Is there a setting or trick to enable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. Turn on `Developer Options`, by tapping on Build number 7+ times.
2. Restart your emulator, by long clicking the **power icon** in the emulator menu and choosing the `Restart` option.
3. Go to the `Add Language` page. Choose your psuedolocale.
4. Add `pseudoLocalesEnabled true` to your `build.gradle` and build your app.

app/build.gradle:

```
  android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
      debug {
        pseudoLocalesEnabled true
      }
    }
```

from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales

Comment: Restarting the device isn't mentioned in the docs, but apparently it's necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can add en_XA and ar_XB locale in android emulator's Custom Locale app.That's it.

[image]